# Can I send a Stripe charge request directly from the frontend?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am wondering if I can send a Stripe request directly from my front-end, because I don't have a back-end. Please note that security isn't an issue, because I won't deploy the project or even use it in any way shape or form.

I am thinking of using axios instead of curl, and it should look like something like this:

[On the Stripe official doc, they use curl on the back-end](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges)

I am also wondering if there's any other key I need to pass. There's a secret key and a publishable key. I am thinking the publishable key is not needed. Also, do I need to activate my account in order for it to work? I don't plan to use it outside of pet projects.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges',
  header: {
    Authorization: 'sk_test_IvnLvlpEpskxJA8u7eEsAOBr00e7fmPyMZ'
  },
  data: {
    amount: '999',
    currency: 'cad',
    description: '',
    source: 'tok_visa'
  }
});
```

I want the same result a curl request would yield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be making this call client-side, both for Security reasons obviously but also because you'd have to make the raw request and handle error handling and such.

Instead, you should use one of Stripe's official [client libraries](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries). Those run server-side, but it doesn't mean you need a separate server. You can just run the code locally on your computer for example by building a PHP script that interacts with your client-side code in the browser.

Another alternative would be to use [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) as there's a client-side-only integration that only requires some javascript. See the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client).